# Using python selenium to choose an option from a dropdown menu with always changing values and text

Tags: python, selenium, dropdown

I want to choose an option from a dropdown menu, but the options' values are always changing.

It worked when I used this code:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[text()='8:30pm Thu Dec 30th 2021']").click()`

but then I have the same problem with the changing text.

I tried solving it with the help of answers to my previous questions (see picture attached), but when I run the code, it cant locate the value, although it is exactly the value that is given.

This was the line of code I used for it:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//option[value='{object_name}']").click()`

And this is the problem I am having:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//option[value='2021-12-30 18:30:00']"} (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.110)

[code not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaJl6.png)

Thanks in advance.

*Added HTML of the dropdown menu:

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HIRd.png)

Comment: Do not post code via images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question. Add them as code into the question.

Comment: //option[@value] You are missing a @.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Select() when working with dropdowns. Here's an example of how to select the related dropdown value:

```
object_time = datetime.today().replace(hour=6, minute=30, second=0) + timedelta(days=1)
object_name = object_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("your_url")

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "bookingend_24750452"))
)

dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "bookingend_24750452"))
dropdown.select_by_value(object_name)
```

Comment: Hey Marco, thanks for answering so fast. I tried this before but it then says:
`Select only works on <select> elements, not on <div>`

Comment: Share the HTML content in your question that you would parse.

Comment: I have added it now.

Comment: As the error message suggests, you have to select a select HTML element, not a div. I changed the code to select the select element by its id. Change to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, but also there I have the problem that the ID always changes...

Comment: You can use XPATH for example to select always the same select. Check out https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath